# Is there anything like Django Graphviz for the Java/Derby world?

Tags: java, django, derby, graphviz

Does anyone know of something like [Django Graphviz](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoGraphviz) for Java/Derby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to inspect the schema of an existing Derby database? Try SQL Squirrel (http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) or dblook (http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/tools/ctoolsdblook.html)